# Locating a specific field in an attribute table using SQL with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, sql, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

I am a beginner at GIS/ArcGIS and have a quick question about locating a field in an attribute table of a feature using SQL. Attached is an image of a (crude) example of the kind of attribute table I am working with, but in Excel instead of in ArcGIS. I am looking to find a specific data point of one city/one demographic group. More specifically, I am attempting to find the records that match a specific value (or value range) in a field that I already know the name of. I know the column/row name, I just need to find the specific value given these two names. For example, how I would I find the population under 10 years of age in New York? I know that doing "City" = 'New York' in the SQL box will highlight the entire row in the attribute table, but I am not sure how to find a specific text field within a row.

[image]

Comment: Hello! I am attempting to find the records that match a specific value (or value range) in a field that you already know the name of (the column/row name) and I clarified that in my question. I know the column/row name (for example, "New York" and "Pop. Under 10 Years") and am looking to find the value that intersects those two. Thanks!!

Comment: Depending on what you really want...`"City" = 'New York' AND "Pop_Under_10_years" = 11` or `"City" = 'New York' OR "Pop_Under_10_years" = 44` (Note that your field name may not be what I've written here, but you have to use the real field name, not the field alias).

Comment: Thank you, that helps clarify!! I appreciate it.